# Connection to a Microsoft SQL Database via VBA (ADODB) with the lowest risk to harm the database

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, readonly

im currently looking for a way to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server Database via VBA (ADODB) with the focus on a minimal risk in harming, block and change the structure of the database. Therefor the access is readonly.

My attemp is the following:

```
Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set TmpRecset = New Recordset

DBConn.ConnectionString = pConnStr
DBConn.Open

On Error GoTo TermConnection

With TmpRecset
    .ActiveConnection = DBConn
    .Source = pQuery
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With

On Error GoTo TermRecordset

//Doing something useful with TmpRecset

On Error GoTo 0

TermRecordset:
TmpRecset.Close
Set TmpRecset.ActiveConnection = Nothing

TermConnection:
DBConn.Close
Set DBConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

And I'm using the following connection string:

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=IP\Database;Initial Catalog=Databasename;Trusted_connection=yes;"
```

I used the manual error handling to ensure, that the recordset and the database is closed whatever happens. Via the parameters of the recordset I define the readonly access.

Are there some other mechanisms to make sure, that the integrity of the Database will be ensured?

Best regards

Comment: How about just connecting via Data>From Other Sources>From SQL Server. You can do SELECT queries in the Edit Query dialog. This post of mine might be useful: http://yoursumbuddy.com/tables-edit-query-dialog/. Otherwise if you are going to stick with VBA, be sure to look at AddParameter and CreateParameter, designed to lessen the chance of SQL injection. But if you're just SELECTING, I'd let the Data menu do the work for you.

Comment: @j_wal-ter: Please mark my answer as "accepted" if that's the case. Otherwise, please let me know what's missing. [How to mark an answer as "accepted".](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Doug! Is it possible that this Selection is executed on every start of the Excel-File?

Comment: Yes it is possible. If the table is already set up, go to Data > Connections > Properties > Usage. You'll also see these choice when you set up the table. There's lots of info about this on the web. BTW putting @ in front of a name in a comment, e.g., @DougGlancy will let SO inform them (me) that you said something to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there is no reasonable security in Excel. All security should reside on the server. If you want to prevent accidental or malicious changes to the database then the database on the server should be read-only or all users should have read-only access to the SQL server. Furthermore, you can implement traces on the server, SQL audit C2, or make use of extended properties. Yet, all of this is on the side of the SQL server. The things you can do on the "client" side (such as Excel in this case) are only support functions. And so the question is (to me) what kind of support functions can I implement in Excel to ensure SQL server safety. Here are some of the things I do:

(1) Make the connection string dynamic using global variables or storing the string on a hidden sheet. Then you can automatically switch between development server and production server. Example:

```
Dim conRCServer As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstResult As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set conRCServer = New ADODB.Connection
conRCServer.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; " _
    & "DATA SOURCE=" & Ref.Range("C2").Value2 & ";" _
    & "INITIAL CATALOG=" & Ref.Range("C4").Value & ";" _
    & "Integrated Security=SSPI "
On Error GoTo SQL_ConnectionError
conRCServer.Open
On Error GoTo 0
```

(2) Have a seperate error handler for connecting to the server and handling SQL syntax errors. Example:

```
Set rstResult = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL = "set nocount on; "
strSQL = strSQL & "/* #" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "{" & WorksheetUsers.Name & "}btnDownloadUserDataFromServer */"
strSQL = strSQL & "select  v.LastName, "
strSQL = strSQL & "        v.FirstName "
strSQL = strSQL & "from    vUsers as v "
strSQL = strSQL & "order by v.LastName, v.FirstName "
rstResult.ActiveConnection = conRCServer
On Error GoTo SQL_StatementError
rstResult.Open strSQL
On Error GoTo 0
```

Here is an error handler for the SQL syntax and in the above example is a seperate handler for the possible SQL connection error.

(3) Incorporate self-identification within the SQL syntax. As you can see in the above example I am also letting the server know which file, which sheet (within the file) and which function within the sheet the user called to execute this statement. If you capture this data on the server with a trace then you can see who is writing their own queries, who is using your standard files and which functions are used (and their respective impact).

(4) If an error occurs you might want to consider writing automated error emails. Example:

```
SQL_ConnectionError:
Y = MsgBox("Cannot connect to the server. Please make sure that you have a working internet connection. " & _
            "Also ensure that are connected to the corporate network and are allowed to access the server. " & _
            "Do you want me to prepare an error-email?", 52, "Problems connecting to Server...")
If Y = 6 Then
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .to = Ref.Range("C7").Value2
        .CC = Ref.Range("C8").Value2
        .Subject = "Problems connecting to database '" & Ref.Range("C4").Value & "' on server '" & Ref.Range("C2").Value & "'"
        .HTMLBody = "<span style=""font-size:10px"">---Automatically generated Error-Email---" & _
                "</span><br><br>Error report from the file '" & _
                "<span style=""color:blue"">" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & _
                "</span>' located and saved on '<span style=""color:blue"">" & _
                ActiveWorkbook.Path & "</span>'.<br>" & _
                "Excel is not able to establish a connection to the server. Technical data to follow." & "<br><br>" & _
                "Computer Name:    <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("COMPUTERNAME") & "</span><br>" & _
                "Logged in as:     <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("USERDOMAIN") & "/" & Environ("USERNAME") & "</span><br>" & _
                "Domain Server:    <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("LOGONSERVER") & "</span><br>" & _
                "User DNS Domain:  <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("USERDNSDOMAIN") & "</span><br>" & _
                "Operating System: <span style=""color:green;"">" & Environ("OS") & "</span><br>" & _
                "Excel Version:    <span style=""color:green;"">" & Application.Version & "</span><br>" & _
                "<br><span style=""font-size:10px""><br>" & _
                "Possible reasons for this error include: (1) no Internet connection, (2) no working VPN connection to the corporate network, " & _
                "(3) the server is currently offline, (4) DNS authentication problems, (5) ... other reasons ..., " & _
                "(6) the user does not have the required permission to connect to the underlying database on the server." & _
                "<br><br>---Automatically generated Error-Email---"
        .Display
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End If
Exit Sub
```

I also looked into your approach of changing the connection parameters. But in most corporate environments I have worked for these connection parameters have been overridden (for example ADODB.Connection.CommandTimeout is overridden by the server's SQL timeout per user or Windows corporate presets if they exist). So, they did not work for me. But the above worked rather well for me and the companies I worked for over the last couple of years.

Let me know if this is the kind of answer you've been looking for.

Comment: @j_wal-ter: Please mark my answer as "accepted" if that's the case. Otherwise, please let me know what's missing. If you don't know how to mark an answer as "accepted" [please click here to find out](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, Ralph. First of all I will define the boundary conditions more precise:
- I can't set the SQL Database readonly in general
- I can't change the config of the SQL Database overall

So when I evaluate your points my only options are to set restrict parameters for TmpRecset and hope that they won't be overwritten and maybe check the used SQL command again just before it is send to the SQL Server. So someone has to change the SQL Query in two positions to edit the Database. Is that correct?

Comment: If your SQL server allows users to change data on the server (DML) or even allows them to change the database structure (DDL) then there is nothing in your code you can do to prevent that other than writing no VBA code to update / change / delete anything on the server. Yet, anbody else can change your VBA code (if it is not protected) or write new VBA code to do just that and the server will accept / implement that. SQL Server security is on the server. Not in Excel or any other Microsoft Office product. If you cannot change the security on the server then you can only hope and monitor.

Comment: Keep in mind that anybody can connect to your SQL with Microsoft Access and easily change all tables delete, update, and insert new records as they see fit (if the server allows it). Access is actually extremely convenient in this respect: (1) go in Access to `File`, `New` (2) Give it a file name with the extension .adp (not .mdb or .accdb) (3) click `Create`. (4) MS Access will ask you if you want to connect to an existing SQL server. Click `Yes`and enter the server name then `Ok`. Then all tables on the server are accessible for change and only the server controls the permissions.