# Is there anyway to extract SQL Queries into Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

Currently I run a morning report every morning. The report has two queries; one I directly copy and paste into excel and the other returns a dynamic list of other queries. I then run those second-level queries and also input those into excel.

Is there anyway to automate this process of SQL -> Excel, through VBA potentially? Keep in mind that the second query returns even more queries to run. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the database source probably. You can use ADO to connect to other databases and paste that data into Excel. Is that what you are look for? Where is the data being pulled from?

Comment: @RyanWildry it's an internal database

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for SSIS

Comment: What database product is it? Ms Access, MySQL, Sql Server, etc?

Comment: Two options: (1) Just go to the `Data` tab in Excel and then select `From other sources` and then `From SQL Server`. The windows you will be guided through just allows you to pull views and tables. But later on you can change that to execute SQL queries (incl. stored procedures). (2) Use the ADO approach as suggested by @RyanWildry. In the following solution are a few VBA code snippets to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289095/connection-to-a-microsoft-sql-database-via-vba-adodb-with-the-lowest-risk-to-h/30299444#30299444

Comment: @RyanWildry it is SQL Server

Comment: @Ralph I'll look into that, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These three sources have everything you need to accomplish what you seek to do. I used them when I attempted the same thing. You'll need to lookup the connection strings if you run into trouble but it's pretty straight forward.
Everything is here:

1) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316934

2) https://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/different-connection-strings-sql-server/

3) [How to query a MS-Access Table from MS-Excel (2010) using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842607/how-to-query-a-ms-access-table-from-ms-excel-2010-using-vba)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have lots of options here.  I'll post one more for you to consider.

http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Excel%20Data%20Export%20to%20SQL%20Server%20Test%20Code