# Exporting SQL Server data to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

We work with a lot of data at my job, and I want to try and find a way to limit the amount of copying from SSMS to an Excel sheet that goes to the client.

What I want to be able to do, using SSIS if possible or any other possible way (Maybe power query?), is to copy the data pulled via a SQL query to an Excel workbook sheet.

For example, I want to do a count on the amount of members by state, I'd have the query run and the results copied to the sheet called "State" in the Excel work book.

Example code:

```
SELECT C.State, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM [dbo].Input I
Join Cassresults C on C.ID = I.ID
group by C.State
order by Count desc
```

The Excel workbook will never change for the client. The only thing that may change are the queries, but those are easily updated.

Is there a way to actually do this or am I nuts for thinking so? I hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: Power Query can definitely do it, but what about just plain using the Data options in Excel itself?

Comment: If these requests are on-demand, you could have a VBA macro to connect to the server and run queries and/or stored procedures.

Comment: If you're not sure what @JohnBustos means, be sure to ask. Could save you many, many hours.

Comment: Here you can find some sample code to get the query run with VBA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289095/connection-to-a-microsoft-sql-database-via-vba-adodb-with-the-lowest-risk-to-h/30299444#30299444 (as proposed by @JohnCappelletti).

Comment: @JohnBustos will the data options in excel actually allow me to do this automatically? My goal with this is to automate filling out the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSAS, SSIS, PowerQuery, PowerBI, Excel PowerPivot, SSRS, and Excel Data Querys all are geared for this type of use.  I would definitely NOT recommend VBA as your users will constantly get a security warning and it is more complex than needed.

For Excel probably a good starting location go to the data tab and click "From Other Sources" and check out the different source types.  From Micrsoft Query gives you the ability to write a query or copy from SSMS.

The only thing is will Data Sources Change?  If so every workbook you create and distribute will the become obsolete and need to be changed.  SSRS is a good choice to allow users to grab the report (and export to Excel) that they need.

When doing SSAS it is great as well but start with PowerPivot in Excel, again data connections move Sharepoint data connection library is a way to combat that.

This is like a BI and reporting design question and you will get a plethora of answers.